# Jquery .Replacewith returns String

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to Check if my Checkbox is checked and if it is checked i want to replace it with a label

```
for (var N = 0; N < Checkboxes; N++) {
    var thischeckbox = Checkboxes[N];
    if ($(thischeckbox).prop("checked") == true) {
        thischeckbox.replaceWith(function () {
            return $("<label> ticked <label/>")
        });
        // thischeckbox.removeAttribute("style");
    }
}
```

But this returns for me function () {return $( ticked )
as a string
is it because it is in a for and can't load quietly?

Comment: `N < Checkboxes` is wrong when `Checkboxes` is an array. `thischeckbox` is a DOM node, hence it calls [`ChildNode.replaceWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/replaceWith) which only can handle [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node)s or strings.

Comment: @tanmay_garg I rolled back your edit, you had removed a crucial information from the question, as "_as a string_" is the core of the question.

Comment: Any particular reason to not just query for all checked boxes? Something like `$("input:checkbox :checked").each(cb => $(cb).replaceWith(()=>$("<label> ticked <label/>")));` ?

Comment: To solve this problem we need to know the content of the used variables. Please take a look at how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @Teemu actually Checkboxes is the count of th checkboxes that i have the code is ok cause i tried to remove the attr and it worked but for replacing returns me not the tag but the string

Comment: If `Checkboxes` is a number, `var thischeckbox = Checkboxes[N]` doesn't make sense ... Please add add the code defining these variables, and the related HTML part would be nice too.

Comment: @Andreas ur way didnt work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you forgot to wrap with dollar sign `thischeckbox` since `replaceWith` is also a jQuery method and you return a jQuery object in the callback

Try below:

```
$(thischeckbox).replaceWith(function () {
    return $("<label> ticked <label/>");
});
```

Comment: We actually don't know, what is stored in `Checkboxes`.

Comment: @Teemu True but it sounds like the iteration works since the question says that a string gets displayed, as the way I understood the situation

Comment: @Teemu Why should it throw an error? [`ChildNode.replaceWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/replaceWith)

Comment: @Andreas Umm ... it shouldn't, my bad.

Comment: i used the sign but  this but doesnt return anything

Comment: @kawmy If this answer works then `Checkboxes` is NOT _"the count of th checkboxes that i have"_

Answer (score 1):

You have some mistakes in your code.

1. in for loop `for(var N = 0; N < Checkboxes; N++)`  here your not checking the length of the checkboxes so it was not entering in the loop,
2. you were returning one function inside of other function
   `replaceWith(function () {return $("<label> ticked <label/>});` which may  coz to confusing of semantic variable of outer scoped

```js
var Checkboxes = $('[type=checkbox]');
for (var N = 0; N < Checkboxes.length; N++) {
  var thischeckbox = Checkboxes[N];
  if ($(thischeckbox).prop("checked") == true) {
            thischeckbox.replaceWith('ticked');
    //thischeckbox.removeAttribute("style");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" checked><br>
<input type="checkbox"><br><input type="checkbox" checked><br><input type="checkbox"><br><input type="checkbox">
```

Comment: And why is 2. a problem?

Comment: that does not actually error that is a warning, and coz it's referred in the loop and it may coz to confusing semantic variable of outer scoped,

Answer (score 1):

Enclosing **thischeckbox** with **jQuery($)** suggested by others works perfect.

The code is :

```js
        $(thischeckbox).replaceWith(function () {
            return $("<label> ticked <label/>")
        });
```

If you are going to replace the checkbox only with the label, there is no need to use the function. Instead you can pass the element directly as the param.

```js
   $(thischeckbox).replaceWith($("<label> ticked <label/>"));
```

Working Demo:

```js
var checkboxes = $('[type = checkbox]')
var checkboxesLength = checkboxes.length;

function replaceCheckboxes(){
  for (var N = 0; N < checkboxesLength; N++) {
    var thischeckbox = checkboxes[N];
    if (thischeckbox.checked) {
        $(thischeckbox).replaceWith(function () {
            return $("<label> ticked <label/>")
        });
        //Alternate
        //$(thischeckbox).replaceWith($("<label> ticked12 <label/>"));
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='item1' type=checkbox />Item1 <br><br>
<input id='item2' type=checkbox />Item2 <br><br>
<input id='item3' type=checkbox />Item3 <br><br>

<br>
<button onclick='replaceCheckboxes()'>Replace </button>
```